# rewriting formula containing covariance and variances

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, correlation, covariance

just trying to follow a formula.

the equation starts of as follows,

```
 1 = sum( xi * (cov(ri, r) / sigma^2(r) )    please note i's are subscripts
```

then next line is the following

```
 1 = sum( (1/sigma(r)) * xi * sigmai * p(ri, r)        p is the correlation coeff
```

I cannot get the second line, sure I'm being stupid and missing something very obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\rho(r_i,r)= \frac{\text{cov}(r_i,r)}{\sigma(r_i)\cdot \sigma(r)}\\\implies \text{cov}(r_i,r) = \rho(r_i,r)\cdot \sigma(r_i)\cdot \sigma(r)$$

Comment: ah yes! Can't believe I missed that!